# Partial Sum of a "nonstandard" series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I am to find the partial sums of a series that takes this format:
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{n}x C^{x-1}
$$

For some constant C. It is not a geometric series due the x there.
I have seen ways of solving the partial sums with assigning it to a constant and subtracting to simplify the series (similar to Wikipedia's entry [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Heuristics) with c - 4c)) but I am wondering how one would solve this in a general case for a sequence of this form.

Comment: with respect to $C$ , what is the derivative of $C^x$.

Comment: If C is a constant, how can you take the derivative with respect to a constant. Lets say C = 3

The derivative of $3^x$ is $3^x * ln(3)$ but that is with respect to x or generally $C^x ln(C)$

Answer (score 1):

Try differentiating both side of $\sum_{k=0}^n y^k = \frac{y^{n+1}-1}{y-1}$ w.r.t. $y$. (for L.H.S. it is done term by term.) Then substitute $y$ to your $C$.

Comment: I am confused as to taking the derivative with respect to a constant, like C or Y

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Here is a direct approach. Note that if the geometric series is given by
$$
G_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x},
$$
then your series is just $G_n'(x)$.

Comment: Your notation is derivative of G, right? I am not used to this notation

Comment: @Marchisio8 yes, correct, $f'(x)$ often denotes $\frac{df}{dx}$